# Serial port data received faster than handled

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, serial-port, invoke

I have a serial port with a baud rate of 115200 coming from an arduino to my C# Winform. I have a data received event that invokes a new thread to add the incoming data to a datatable. The datatable is bound to a datagridview. The problem I am noticing is that there is an increasing delay between the serial port receiving data and updataing the datagridview with the new data. I have tested the incoming data with a serial monitor and there is no delay, so the problem is somewhere in my C# code. The purpose of the newest button in the code below is to keep only the newest incoming message ID and remove the old message with the same ID from the datagridview. This is my first C# project and I have never worked with serial ports before.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));
    }
    catch (System.TimeoutException)
    {
    }
}

private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    string inData = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    if (dtFromGrid == null)
    {
        dtFromGrid = new DataTable();
        dtFromGrid.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(String));
        dtFromGrid.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
        dtFromGrid.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        dtFromGrid.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(String));
    }

    DataRow dr = dtFromGrid.NewRow();
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    dr["Time"] = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
    ts.Milliseconds);
    dr["ID"] = inData.Split(new char[] { '<', ',' })[1];
    dr["Name"] = inData.Split(new char[] { ',', '/' })[1];
    dr["Data"] = inData.Split(new char[] { '/', '>' })[1];
    dtFromGrid.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

    if (NewestButton.Text == "Chronological")
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dtFromGrid.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() == dtFromGrid.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString())
            {
                dtFromGrid.Rows[i].Delete();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dtFromGrid.Rows.Count == 51)
    {
        dtFromGrid.Rows[50].Delete();
    }
    dtFromGrid.AcceptChanges();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtFromGrid;
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];

    if (logFile != "")
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logFile))
        {
            DataRow row = dtFromGrid.Rows[0];
            object[] array = row.ItemArray;
            int col = 0;
            for (col = 0; col < array.Length - 1; col++)
            {
                sw.Write(array[col].ToString() + "\t|\t");
            }
            sw.Write(array[col].ToString());
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first, you forgot that *By default, the [`ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline.aspx) method will block until a line is received*. Your code does all job in UI thread.

Comment: Is it bad to use ReadLine()? My arduino sends in the format <ID,Name/Data> all on one line. I assume that since that data received event occurs only when data is detected that ReadLine() would not hold up the application?

Comment: Also, I thought that an invoke would start a new thread. Maybe I interpreted my research incorrectly. How would I perform this on a new thread?

Comment: [`DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event may get triggered after receiving just 1 byte. And then you block UI thread until [`NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline.aspx) will arraive. You could simple call `ReadLine()` in the `DataReceived` event and then *invoke* method to proceed received string in UI thread.

Comment: how would I go about calling `ReadLine()` in the `DataReceived` event? I am trying to prevent the UI from hanging while the string is processed. would a new thread perform better and if so how would I set that up?

Comment: @Sinatr I have an if statement before `DataReceived` that uses a `ReadLine()` to check if the string begins with "<" which is always my first character in each string. `DataReceived` only operates if this is detected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to establish a serial connection between Arduino and a C#/.NET program is to use the [CmdMessenger](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-Libraries/tree/master/CmdMessenger) library. The usage is quite straightforward and there are several [examples and documentation](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger) resources on the web.

CmdMessenger uses command queues with processing strategies in threads, so that you should have no performance problems.